# Change Style of an element inside iframe - cross domain (I own the second domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am the owner of 2 domains

```
   1. www.example1.com 
   2. www.example2.com
```

I want to accomplish the following two tasks.

1. I want to load the html page from example2.com into an iframe. (done)
2. i want to change the style of an element exists in the html inside the iframe content.

i have tried document.domain in both the pages, but it does not work.

Please note: i have the full control on both the domains.

Please help, i have been stucked in this issue since 2 days.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-change-css-iframe-content/ -I have not tried. But this might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you own both domains you can do this by `window.postMessage`.

In your parent document:

```
embededIframe.contentWindow.postMessage('changeStyle', 'http://www.example1.com');
```

In your child document:

```
handleMessage = function(e) {
  if(e.origin === 'http://www.example1.com') {
    var action = e.data.split(':')[0]
    if(action === 'changeStyle') {
      //do style change
    }
  }
}
window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage, false);
```

More information can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)

Answer (score 0):

**You are not supposed to** be able to do that. **It's a security feature** of browsers not to allow cross domain manipulation like that. Imagine the havoc I could wreck if I could run any script or restyling on any third party domain content that I'm showing you.

**It doesn't matter if you own both the domains or not, but the technique you are trying to use is not possible**

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.postMessage() to pass data values from your parent window to iframe window. So you can pass your css values with this method. 
Mode details for window.postMessage() is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage)